# Java FX Why should I use SimpleProperties and not just the normal nativ variables?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm ceating a game with Java FX at the moment and I'm at a point where I start to add gui elements which show data of the game model underneath.
I came across the TableView and all example Implementations worked with SimpleProperties in the Model Class.

First I thought it's no real difference, but for example you can't do this if `amount` is an SimpleDoubleProperty:

```
amount += 10;
```

So why should I use it this way and can't I use normal variables and display it with them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX properties are observable and bindable. This allows controls to automatically update if the data is changed. A regular Java variable cannot be natively "observed" in this way, so if you don't use the JavaFX properties, you end up having to wire all changes to the UI control yourself. See the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) for more details.

Note that you can do

```
amount.set(amount.get()+10);
```

as an equivalent to

```
amount += 10 ;
```